# Derivative of function with large number of arguments

Tags: functions, function-construction, arguments

I have a function which depends on more than 30 parameters and I want to symbolically compute the derivatives with respect to the individual parameters.

From the documentation of the `D` operator I got the impression that I have to explicitly mention all parameters in the function definition. Is there a way around it? That is, is it possible to take the derivative of a function which is an expression of another symbol, which doesn't appear in the function signature?

If not, is there a way to write the function parameter list on multiple lines, for example like this:

```
Foo[(* These parameters describe... *)
     x11, y12, z13,
    (* And these parameters describe.... *)
     x21, y22, y23,
    (* Many more parameters... *)] := (* Function implementation... *)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `Dt[]` function?

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Define the variables using an [`indexed variable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html)

```
n = 3; (* change as desired *)

var = Array[x, n];
```

Define the function

```
Evaluate[f @@ var] = Sqrt[Total@var^2]

(* Sqrt[(x[1] + x[2] + x[3])^2] *)
```

Taking the partial derivatives

[image]

```
D[f @@ var, Sequence @@ var]

(* (3 (x[1] + x[2] + x[3])^3)/((x[1] + x[2] + x[3])^2)^(5/2) - (
 3 (x[1] + x[2] + x[3]))/((x[1] + x[2] + x[3])^2)^(3/2) *)
```

or for a vector derivative

[image]

```
D[f @@ var, {var}]

(* {(x[1] + x[2] + x[3])/Sqrt[(x[1] + x[2] + x[3])^2], (
 x[1] + x[2] + x[3])/Sqrt[(x[1] + x[2] + x[3])^2], (
 x[1] + x[2] + x[3])/Sqrt[(x[1] + x[2] + x[3])^2]} *)
```